# R plot binary timeseries

Tags: r, plot

I have a dataset where I have a binary value on a timeline. 
So for example:

```
Date, Event

January-29-2014, 1 
January-29-2014, 0 
January-29-2014, 1 
January-29-2014, 1 
January-30-2014, 0
```

I would like to plot the 1,0 on a timeline(by Date) and in color (red bar = 1,blue bar = 0)
How can I achieve this ? 
How do you call this ? e.g. binary timeline plotting :)

Sorry and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is think this is what you want. Using fake data:

```
n = 100
x = seq(n)
y = sample(0:1, n, replace=TRUE)

DF = data.frame(Date=x, Event=y)

ones = rep(1, nrow(DF))

colors = c("blue", "red")
plot(DF$Date, ones, type="h", col=colors[DF$Event +1],
     ylim=c(0,1))
```

[image: theplot]

Comment: Yep that is exactly what I wanted. Only I discovered that my data seems to have only one header. "2014-01-31     0" is one entry. So now I am trying to split that in two columns, so I can do what you suggested. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you want. Do you want aggregate data by day. Like an epidemiological curve?

```
library(lubridate)
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)

dat = read.table(header=TRUE, text='Date Event

January-29-2014, 1 
January-29-2014, 0 
January-29-2014, 1 
January-29-2014, 1 
January-30-2014, 0 ')

dat$Date = mdy(dat$Date)

agg = ddply(dat, 'Date', summarise, Events = sum(Event))

ggplot(data=agg, aes(x = Date, y = Events)) + geom_bar(stat='identity') + scale_x_datetime(expand=c(1,0))
```

Output:
[image]